# How to highlight matched word in jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, solr

I want to highlight solr search result in jquery ui auto-complete with the word input by the user. I have tried the following code but it will just wrap the word like "<strong>word</strong>" rather than making it bold. Please help.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#autosearch").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8983/solr/select",
            data: { 
                q: request.term,
                fl: "name",
                wt: 'json',
            }, 
            dataType: "jsonp",
            jsonp: 'json.wrf',

            success: function(data){
                var regex = new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + request.term.replace(/([\^\$\(\)\[\]\{\}\*\.\+\?\|\\])/gi, "\\$1") + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi");
                var result = $.map(data.response.docs, function(item){
                    return item.name.replace(regex, "<strong>$1</strong>");
                });
                response( result );
            }
          }); 
         },
        minLength: 2
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, for example:

change `<strong>$1</strong>` with `<strong class='thick'>$1</strong>`

and then add this to your css:

```
strong.thick {font-weight:bold;}
```

Comment: My question is <strong> tag is rendered as string not as HTML.

Comment: can you send the code when you actually use your result variable in your html?